# Session Fixation - Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net, session, testing

I am using Form Authentication is ASP.NET. I am running penetrating testing for a school project. I am using LENS -ASP.NET PENETRATING TESTING TOOL. In the results it told me that my application could be vulnerable to session fixation. Does anyone know how this can be mitigated against?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A session fixation is an attack in which one person fixates another person's session identifier (SID).

The attack starts with the attacker visiting the website and establishing a valid session, when the application delivers a cookie containing the Session ID, the attacker has fixed, or locked in, a known good session. The attacker will then trick the victim into using this Session ID. At this point the attacker and victim share the same Session ID. Now anytime the information stored in this fixated session is used to either make decisions for the victim or display information only the victim should see, can be potentially used and viewed by the attacker! You can [read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

The only workaround on this would be for ASP.NET to **issue a NEW session ID after any successful authentication**, That way once the victim logs in, the attacker will have no access to the session. Another point to remember: **NEVER deliver session until the user logs in.**

Remember, in ASP.net `Session.Abandon()` is not sufficient for this task, it does not remove the session ID cookie from the user's browser, so any new request to the same application, after the session is abandoned, will use the same session ID and a new Session State instance! [As Microsoft states here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918). You need to abandon the session **and** clear session ID cookie:

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

It's also a good practice to change the Form Authentication cookie name, in your `web.config` file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".CookieName" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Here's a good article on [Session Attacks and ASP.NET](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/06/24/session-attacks-and-aspnet-part-2) and how to resolve it.

Comment: Sorry to revive a 6-year-old question, but your answer does not work.  If I add the code you describe after a successful login there is no error, but the user is simply re-directed back to the login page.

Comment: @TomRegan Simply resetting the session on the login page, before the user even logs in, is enough to prevent the session fixation.

Comment: @KamyarNazeri do you have a code sample to demonstrate what you mean by "Simply resetting the session on the login page".  I can't get this to work; no matter where I put this reset the user gets redirected back to the login page.